# using "this" or explicit object in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript code I have,

```
for (var i=0;i<divList.length;i++){
    divList[i].style.backgroundColor="#AA0000";

    divList[i].onclick = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor="#00AA00";
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering why I can't use

```
divList[i].style.backgroundColor="#00AA00";
```

Answer (score 3):

*Theoretically*, you could, but practically, you can't for a simple reason.

By the time that onclick function gets called, the value of `divList` and `i` will not be what you expect them to. `i` will be inherited by lexical scope, and it would be the same `i` for all of the `onclick` handlers, and it would be `divList.length` because that's the last value that got assigned to it.

Essentially, you would try to set the color of the Nth div to green, but you only have N-1 items.

There are several ways you could overcome that, but the simplest course of action would be to just use `this`. The JavaScript engine would call your function and bind `this` to the element that triggered the event, in this case, it would be the `div` element that got clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more information about this topic:

(Point 6) https://www.toptal.com/javascript/10-most-common-javascript-mistakes

> This is because, by the time onclick is invoked for any of the elements, the for loop will have completed and the value of **i** will already be 10 (for all of them).

Test it out: (Notice the console.log and the green box)

```js
var divList = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

    for (var i=0;i<divList.length;i++){
        divList[i].style.backgroundColor="red";

        divList[i].onclick = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor="blue";
          divList[i-1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
            console.log("i:", i, "element:", i-1);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div>foo 0</div>
<div>foo 1</div>
<div>foo 2</div>
<div>foo 3</div>
<div>foo 4</div>
<div>foo 5</div>
<div>foo 6</div>
<div>foo 7</div>
<div>foo 8</div>
<div>foo 9</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, added an explanation.